# How does #:~:text= work for highlighting text?

Tags: http, url

When following a link from the Google search page, I often see the most relevant part of the page highlighted like so:

[image: Wikipedia page with some highlighted text]

Looking at the URL, I see bits of the highlighted text appear after the #:~:text= anchor (hash, colon, tilde, colon, text - in case someone is trying to Google this question):

> [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#:~:text=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%83-,%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#:%7E:text=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BA%D1%83-,%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Is this notation (#:~:text=) Wikipedia-specific or is it a more standard way of highlighting text on a web page? Where can I read up on this? So far my google-fu has failed me.

Comment: I keep seeing people spread this kind of URLs for all sorts of websites and I have no idea where they come from.